# What is the hash to a terminal command?

Tags: mac

I entered a Terminal command into TextEdit, but i don't know the hash to Terminal, so I can't change it. I tried changing it into .bash and .rtf, but they don't work. Help Plz???

Answer (score 1):

When using TextEdit to write shell scripts or similar,

- make sure that TextEdit is in plan text (and not in rich text) mode (check the format menu)
- use `#!/bin/bash` as the first line
- run `chmod +x /path/to/file` once after saving it
- use `/path/to/file` (or, if it is in the current directory, `./file`) to execute it